# webservice with different Os

Tags: web-services

1. I created webservice in my system and
   need to diploy it in a server which
   contain OS other than windows,say
   Mac or any others,so that those
   working on Java or any other
   technologies can acees my
   webservice.Is there any possible solution
2. other than visual studio IDE is
   there any utility for creating
   webservice.i Heard about wsdlgen.exe
   something like that .Is this useful
   in this type of situation whoich i
   explained above

Comment: Define "deploy" in this case - the *server* is not especially relevant to the client (I'm generalising) that's part of the point of a web service, that you talk using defined protocols to an API and don't need to worry about the underlying server platform. Upshot is that in theory any development tool that can consume web services will be able to consume web services served from a windows platform

Comment: But i heard IIS is a mandaory for deployment of webservice which will be only on windows OS(microsoft).

Comment: Okey as per your comment if i deploy webservice from my system through IIS ,,those sitting in remoteserver working on dfferent technology which is on differnt OS can access my webservice

Comment: IIS is only mandatory if there isn't another server that will host a .NET server application.

Answer (score 0):

A web service can be used (if written right) from many OS, however - when you say deploy - if you mean the actual service executable - you don't need to deploy it (probably you can't even) on mac or linux in order for other tech to access it.

you need to deploy it on the framework that you used to develope it (like win server for WCF / other dot net or c++ based server) and make sure it can be accessed by other technologies - by it's contracts / endpoints ect.

They will access it through tcp/ip probably http, using a common language that they can both talk.

** it doesn't matter if you deploy on IIS or as a service, or as a console application - as long as it implement the right standard other OS based client can access it.

Comment: But i heard IIS is a mandaory for deployment of webservice which will be only on windows OS(microsoft).

Comment: Okey as per your comment if i deploy webservice from my system through IIS ,,those sitting in remoteserver working on dfferent technology which is on differnt OS can access my webservice

Answer (score 0):

Webservices are a platform independent setup. A webservice is a standardized way of communicating structured data. The language of the webservice is XML, thus it can be interpreted by most languages, and platforms (I haven't heard of webservices being used on DOS 3 yet. )

Your implementation of the webservice must be deployed to the compatible server. If you used a .NET language that is most likely on IIS (mono on its respected mod_net). If its in Java then on Tomcat, JBoss, etc.

Once you have deployed your webservice any client can access your webservice. The output of the webservice is [typically] contained in an HTTP message. Your client is not required to be written in the same language as the service its self, nor is it require the same platform that it is hosted on. I've heard of FPGA's using webservces, and I've been consumed a web service (written in java) from a Nokia N800 (using gSoap as the client).